# How to convert GetDate() to "YYYY-MM-DD-HHMM" format?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005

I've been looking for the answer and could not find the exact one satisfying my needs.

I'm looking for the way to convert `Datetime` value into `YYYY-MM-DD-HHMM` format.

I tried that one:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(), 120) + replace(convert(varchar(5),getdate(),108),':','')
```

But it did not give me the right results

Is there any practical way to do it?

Comment: What is your DBMS/version?

Comment: I have SQL Server 2012

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? 
Show us ur effort, it appears that you are just **asking us to do it for you**.

Answer (score 11):

In `SQL Server 2012` or later you can use the built-in [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) function for this:

```
Select  Format(GetDate(), N'yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm')
```

Comment: Nice.  I always forget that after 15+ years, they finally added this in.

Comment: Actually, I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 but the version of Microsoft SQL Server is 2005

Comment: @gene That's going to severely limit your options - the SSMS version doesn't affect what functions are available to you. I've re-tagged the question with the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 select CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(), 20) + '-' + replace(convert(varchar(5),getdate(),108),':','')
```

I'm not sure if this is efficient or not, though